Command to create postgres dump running fine on terminal but not as a cron job
I have a cron job which regularly backs up data to Exoscale servers. The cron job should back up to the server if the postgres database dump is of considerable size. When executing the cron job, the size of the database dump is coming out to be a default 4kb, which should not be the case. However, when running the same command on a terminal the size of the database dump comes out to be entirely different and much larger (800M). Looking at the cron logs, everything seems fine too.
docker exec -it $STAGING_CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash -c 'PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD pg_dump -U $POSTGRES_USER $POSTGRES_DB' | gzip &> /root/staging.sql.gz

On checking the entries through crontab -e, crontab looks like this
  30 1   *   *   *    bash /root/backup/scripts/backup_exoscale.sh
  30 1   *   *   6    bash /root/backup/scripts/backup_scaleway.sh
  30 1   *   *   7    bash /root/backup/scripts/backup_rotation_exoscale.sh

The cron log just shows the following line and nothing else in the logs.
(root) CMD (bash /root/backup/scripts/backup_exoscale.sh)


Presumably one or more of the environment variables are missing. Cron runs a restricted environment. Set a MAILTO for the job and print the environment-vars so you can see.

Using -i for a noninteractive docker exec seems suspicious.
